# Avoid re-create activity when click on notification in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-notifications

I am now working on a notification reminder, if the user click on the notification , it will open the app.

However, the problem is , if I have already open the app, when I click on the notification it still create a new activity, so , there are two activity in total.

How can I achieve like this? If the user has already open the app , just do nothing, if not , then open the app. Thanks for helping.

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {
    private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    Notification myNotification;
    Vibrator v;

    public AlarmService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        v.vibrate(5000);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, myIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        myNotification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.notify_title))
                .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.notify_msg) + "\n" 
                        + getResources().getString(R.string.reminder_1) + "aaa\n"
                        + getResources().getString(R.string.reminder_2) + "vvv\n"
                        + getResources().getString(R.string.reminder_3) + "cccc\n"
                        + getResources().getString(R.string.reminder_5) + "dddd\n")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND).setAutoCancel(false)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).build();

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);
    }

}
```

Comment: I've never seen an application that creates notifications while user is using it, i.e. if user is using your application, notify him trough the application itself.

Comment: Modern phones have a lot of memory. So your application could be somewhere in stack but not destroyed. So in this case need bring app to front and inside app show something to user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```
public static  void startNotification(Service service,  String message) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(service);
        if(prefs.getBoolean("pref_NotificationDisplayed", true)){
            // Creates an Ongoing Notification
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(service.getApplicationContext()).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle("Title").setContentText(message);

            Intent toLaunch = new Intent(service.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            toLaunch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
            PendingIntent intentBack = PendingIntent.getActivity(service.getApplicationContext(),   0,toLaunch, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            //PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(intentBack);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) service.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            // Send Notification
            Notification primaryNotification = mBuilder.build();
            primaryNotification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
            mNotificationManager.notify(10001,primaryNotification);
        }

    }
```

Thats it...